# Passing Spring Page in get request

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot

I need to send get request from spring application to another spring application using resttamplate.exchange, and if I send a request like:

```
public Page<DenominationLogActivityResponseDto> getLogActivities(String token, Integer page,
      Integer limit, String sortBy, String order) {

    HttpHeaders headers = addTokenHeader(token);
    HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<>(null, headers);

    UriComponents uriComponents = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(
            masterUrl + "/denomination/log?page={page}&limit={limit}&order={order}&sortBy{sortBy}")
        .queryParam("page", page)
        .queryParam("limit", limit)
        .queryParam("order", order)
        .queryParam("sortBy", sortBy)
        .build();
    ResponseEntity<BaseResponse<Page<DenominationLogActivityResponseDto>>> logActivityResponse =
        restTemplate.exchange(
            uriComponents.toUriString(),
            HttpMethod.GET,
            httpEntity,
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {
            }, page, limit, order, sortBy);
    if (!logActivityResponse.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
      throw new TransactionException(
          logActivityResponse.getBody().getStatus(),
          logActivityResponse.getBody().getMessage(),
          logActivityResponse.getBody().getErrorMessage());
    }
    return logActivityResponse.getBody().getData();
  }
```

to another spring apps:

```
    @GetMapping("/log")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getViewTableDenomination(@RequestParam(required = false) Integer page,
                                                        @RequestParam(required = false) Integer limit,
                                                        @RequestParam(required = false) String sortBy,
                                                        @RequestParam(required = false) String order) {
        
        Page<ViewTableResponseDto> data = service.getDenominationViewTable(page, limit, sortBy, order);
        
        BaseResponse<Page<ViewTableResponseDto>> response = new BaseResponse<>(
                String.valueOf(HttpStatus.OK.value()),
                "Success",
                null,
                data
        );
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok(response);
    }
```

I got an error saying:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `org.springframework.data.domain.Page` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
```